# running exe built by visual studio in cmd does not produce an output

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv, cmd

So I'm trying to do some image processing on visual studio 2013 and wrote a piece of code. When I use the built-in local windows debugger to run the code, the code works and produce a output file in my project folder. But when I run the '*.exe' file, built by the same code through visual studio 2013, in cmd with the same argument, I couldn't find any output file. And based on the speed, the '*.exe' file should be running, but it just doesn't produce anything..... What could be happening... Helps appreciated...

code shown below...it's just calling some other function and save the output.

```
#include "saliency/saliency.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s image\n", argv[0] );
        return -1;
    }
    Mat im = imread( argv[1] );
    Saliency saliency;
    Mat_<float> sal = saliency.saliency( im );

    double adaptive_T = 2.0 * sum( sal )[0] / (sal.cols*sal.rows);
    while (sum( sal > adaptive_T )[0] == 0)
        adaptive_T /= 1.2;
    printf(argv[1]);
    std::string a (argv[1]);
    std::string b ("\\");
    unsigned found = a.find_last_of(b);
    std::string c = a.substr(found+1);
    std::string d = ("saliency_");
    std::string e = d + c;
    //imshow( "im", im );
    //imshow( "sal", sal );
    imwrite(e, sal*255);
    //imshow( "T", sal > adaptive_T );
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Update:
 I find the output file at C:\Windows\SysWOW64.... Anyone knows why it's saved there?

Comment: Please show some code. It's hard to guess otherwise.